# How can i generate a "connect time over time" graph in grafana with jmeter+influxDB+Grafana Stack?

Tags: performance, http, jmeter, grafana, influxdb

I know that jmeter has a listener that generates such a graph like so:

[image]

But i want this in a grafana dashboard, i am using the **InfluxDbBackendListenerClient** and these are my table columns in influxDB:

```
"columns": [
                 "time",
                 "application",
                 "avg",
                 "count",
                 "countError",
                 "endedT",
                 "hit",
                 "max",
                 "maxAT",
                 "meanAT",
                 "min",
                 "minAT",
                 "pct90.0",
                 "pct95.0",
                 "pct99.0",
                 "rb",
                 "responseCode",
                 "responseMessage",
                 "sb",
                 "startedT",
                 "statut",
                 "transaction"
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Metrics Exposed](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) chapter of the [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#realtime-results) Connect Time is not something which is available as per [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html)

You can come up with a custom implementation of the [AbstractBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html) which will collect and send Connect Times.

Alternatively you can substitute a metric you're not interested in, for example `Sent Bytes` with the Connect Time. It can be done using i.e. JSR223 PostProcessor and the following simple code:

```
prev.setSentBytes(prev.getConnectTime())
```

[image]

as you can see upon execution `Sent Bytes` value becomes equal to `Connect Time` value hence you can plot it in Grafana amending the chart title:

[image]

Don't forget to appropriately place the JSR223 PostProcessor according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) so it would be applied to all the Samplers

In the above example `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see the Javadoc for all available functions/properties.